# ZXing onActivityResult not called multiple times

Tags: android, camera, zxing

I'm trying to integrate ZXing in my project, but having problems.  It works correctly on the first scan, and on the second scan.  But on the third+ scans the onActivityResult method never gets fired.

Here is where I start the scan:

```
public void performScan(){
IntentIntegrator scanIntegrator = new IntentIntegrator(thisActivity);
                scanIntegrator.initiateScan();
}
```

Here is my onActivityResult method:

```
@Override
    public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent intent) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, intent);
    //retrieve scan result
        Log.w("ZZ", activityName + ": onActivityResult ... requestCode=" + requestCode + " ... resultCode=" + resultCode);
        //BT_debugger.showIt(activityName + ": onActivityResult ... requestCode=" + requestCode + " ... resultCode=" + resultCode);
        if (resultCode == RESULT_OK){
        IntentResult scanningResult = IntentIntegrator.parseActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, intent);
        if (scanningResult != null) {
            //we have a result
            String scanContent = scanningResult.getContents();
            //resultText.setText(scanContent);
            if (scanContent.length()>0) loadQuestion(scanContent);
            else {
                Toast toast = Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                        "No scan data received!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
                toast.show();
            }
        }
        else{
            Toast toast = Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                    "No scan data received!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
            toast.show();
        }
        }
    }
```

And here is the resulting LogCat starting with the scan that doesn't work.

```
09-02 01:24:48.310    435-13722/? I/ActivityManager: START u0 {act=com.google.zxing.client.android.SCAN cat=[android.intent.category.DEFAULT] flg=0x4080000 pkg=com.google.zxing.client.android cmp=com.google.zxing.client.android/.CaptureActivity} from pid 8312
09-02 01:24:48.310    435-13722/? W/ActivityManager: startActivity called from non-Activity context; forcing Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK for: Intent { act=com.google.zxing.client.android.SCAN cat=[android.intent.category.DEFAULT] flg=0x4080000 pkg=com.google.zxing.client.android cmp=com.google.zxing.client.android/.CaptureActivity }
09-02 01:24:48.340    8312-8312/com.testrotary I/Choreographer: Skipped 50 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
09-02 01:24:48.410    8312-8312/com.testrotary W/ZZ: Cr_rr_qrreader:onPause (BASE CLASS)
09-02 01:24:48.430      435-682/? I/ActivityManager: Config changes=1480 {1.0 310mcc?mnc en_US ldltr sw600dp w961dp h528dp 213dpi lrg land finger -keyb/v/h -nav/h s.259}
09-02 01:24:48.550      435-487/? I/InputReader: Reconfiguring input devices.  changes=0x00000004
09-02 01:24:48.550      435-487/? I/InputReader: Device reconfigured: id=2, name='elan-touchscreen', size 800x1280, orientation 1, mode 1, display id 0
09-02 01:24:48.550      435-487/? I/InputReader: Reconfiguring input devices.  changes=0x00000004
09-02 01:24:48.550      435-487/? I/InputReader: Device reconfigured: id=2, name='elan-touchscreen', size 800x1280, orientation 1, mode 1, display id 0
09-02 01:24:48.620    4263-4271/? W/MediaPlayer-JNI: MediaPlayer finalized without being released
09-02 01:24:48.620    4263-4267/? D/dalvikvm: GC_CONCURRENT freed 407K, 13% free 8241K/9396K, paused 7ms+26ms, total 63ms
09-02 01:24:48.640    4263-4263/? I/PlatformSupportManager: Using implementation class com.google.zxing.client.android.common.executor.HoneycombAsyncTaskExecInterface of interface com.google.zxing.client.android.common.executor.AsyncTaskExecInterface for SDK 11
09-02 01:24:48.720      520-520/? D/PhoneStatusBar: mSettingsPanelGravity = 8388661
09-02 01:24:48.760    8312-8312/com.testrotary W/ZZ: testrotary_appDelegate: onTrimMemory with level: 20
09-02 01:24:48.820    4263-4263/? I/com.google.zxing.client.android.camera.open.OpenCameraInterface: No camera facing back; returning camera #0
09-02 01:24:48.820      125-459/? I/AwesomePlayer: setDataSource_l(URL suppressed)
09-02 01:24:48.850    3245-3249/? D/dalvikvm: GC_CONCURRENT freed 386K, 8% free 7878K/8488K, paused 72ms+2ms, total 188ms
09-02 01:24:48.860      125-459/? I/AwesomePlayer: setDataSource_l(URL suppressed)
09-02 01:24:48.890      125-459/? I/CameraClient: Opening camera 0
09-02 01:24:48.890      125-459/? I/NvOmxCamera: HAL_camera_device_open: open camera 0
09-02 01:24:48.920     125-8922/? E/: ioctl SetWhiteBalance failed: -1
09-02 01:24:48.920      125-459/? E/NvOmxCameraSettingsParser: Param type 70 not supported
09-02 01:24:48.920      125-459/? I/NvOmxCamera: HAL_camera_device_open: opened camera 0 (0x4761bb20)
09-02 01:24:48.930    4263-4263/? I/CameraConfiguration: Screen resolution: Point(1280, 736)
09-02 01:24:48.930    4263-4263/? I/CameraConfiguration: Supported preview sizes: 1280x720 960x720 720x576 704x576 800x448 720x480 768x432 640x480 720x408 480x480 352x288 320x240 176x144
09-02 01:24:48.930    4263-4263/? I/CameraConfiguration: Using largest suitable preview size: Point(1280, 720)
09-02 01:24:48.930    4263-4263/? I/CameraConfiguration: Camera resolution: Point(1280, 720)
09-02 01:24:48.930    4263-4263/? I/CameraConfiguration: Initial camera parameters: preferred-preview-size-for-video=720x576;rotation-values=0,90,180,270;zoom=0;recording-hint=false;max-num-detected-faces-hw=0;video-stabilization=false;zoom-supported=true;whitebalance=auto;video-stabilization-values=false,true;jpeg-quality=95;nv-flip-preview=off;preview-format-values=yuv420p,yuv420sp;rotation=0;jpeg-thumbnail-quality=90;preview-format=yuv420sp;metering-areas=(0,0,0,0,0);video-frame-format-values=yuv420p;video-size-values=40x30,176x144,320x240,352x288,640x480,704x576,720x480,720x576,768x432,1280x720;nv-flip-preview-values=off,vertical,horizontal,both;preview-size=320x240;focal-length=2.080;preview-frame-rate-values=5,8,10,15,20,24,25,30;max-num-metering-areas=0;preview-frame-rate=30;nv-flip-still=off;focus-mode-values=fixed;jpeg-thumbnail-width=320;video-size=1280x720;preview-fps-range-values=(4000,60000);jpeg-thumbnail-size-values=0x0,320x240;zoom-ratios=100,125,150,175,200,225,250,275,300,325,350,375,400,425,450,475,500,525,550,575,600,625,650,675,700,725,750,775,800;preview-size-values=176x144,320x240,352x288,480x480,640x480,704x576,720x408,720x480,720x576,768x432,800x448,960x720,1280x720;recording-hint-values=false,true;picture-size-values=320x240,480x480,640x480,800x600,1024x768,1280x720,1280x960;preview-fps-range=4000,60000;auto-whitebalance-lock=false;min-exposure-compensation=-20;antibanding=off;max-num-focus-areas=0;vertical-view-angle=72.600;horizontal-view-angle=72.600;video-stabilization-supported=false;jpeg-thumbnail-height=240;smooth-zoom-supported=true;focus-mode=fixed;nv-flip-still-values=off,vertical,horizontal,both;auto-whitebalance-lock-supported=true;video-frame-format=yuv420p;picture-format-values=jpeg,jfif,exif;max-exposure-compensation=20;video-snapshot-supported=true;exposure-compensation=0;exposure-compensation-step=0.1;auto-exposure-lock=false;effect-values=mono,negative,none,posterize,sepia,aqua,solarize,nv-vivid,nv-emboss;picture-size=1280x960;max-zoom=28;effect=none;whitebalance-values=auto,incandescent,fluorescent,daylight;picture-format=jpeg;focus-distances=0.95,1.9,Infinity;auto-exposure-lock-values=false,true;auto-exposure-lock-supported=true;auto-whitebalance-lock-values=false,true;antibanding-values=off,auto,50hz,60hz
09-02 01:24:48.930    4263-4263/? I/CameraConfiguration: Supported values: null
09-02 01:24:48.940    4263-4263/? I/CameraConfiguration: Settable value: null
09-02 01:24:48.940    4263-4263/? I/CameraConfiguration: Supported values: [fixed]
09-02 01:24:48.940    4263-4263/? I/CameraConfiguration: Settable value: null
09-02 01:24:48.940    4263-4263/? I/CameraConfiguration: Supported values: [fixed]
09-02 01:24:48.940    4263-4263/? I/CameraConfiguration: Settable value: null
09-02 01:24:48.940    4263-4263/? I/DecodeThread: Hints: {POSSIBLE_FORMATS=[CODABAR, CODE_39, CODE_93, CODE_128, DATA_MATRIX, EAN_8, EAN_13, ITF, QR_CODE, RSS_14, RSS_EXPANDED, UPC_A, UPC_E], NEED_RESULT_POINT_CALLBACK=com.google.zxing.client.android.ViewfinderResultPointCallback@420c8040}
09-02 01:24:48.960     125-8929/? D/NvOsDebugPrintf: NvMMLiteBlockCreate : Block : BlockType = 1
09-02 01:24:48.970     125-8929/? D/NvOsDebugPrintf: NvMMLiteJPEGEncGetBufferRequirements : BufferSize 1843200
09-02 01:24:49.020     125-8922/? D/: Camera fd open as: 151
09-02 01:24:49.550     125-8929/? D/NvOsDebugPrintf: Image Physically rotated in DZ
09-02 01:24:49.550     125-8929/? D/NvOsDebugPrintf: NvMMExif_Orientation_0_Degrees= 1
09-02 01:24:49.550      125-889/? E/NvOmxCamera: OMX_ERRORTYPE android::NvOmxCamera::getCameraStereoMode(NvxComponent*, NvOmxCameraUserStereoMode&): Error: invalid NVX mode 0.
09-02 01:24:49.550      125-889/? E/NvOmxCamera: OMX_ERRORTYPE android::NvOmxCamera::getCameraStereoModeAndCaptureInfo(NvxComponent*, NvOmxCameraUserStereoMode&, NVX_STEREOCAPTUREINFO&): getCameraStereoMode failed with 0x00000000
09-02 01:24:49.580    4263-4263/? I/PlatformSupportManager: Using implementation class com.google.zxing.client.android.common.executor.HoneycombAsyncTaskExecInterface of interface com.google.zxing.client.android.common.executor.AsyncTaskExecInterface for SDK 11
09-02 01:24:49.580    4263-4263/? I/AutoFocusManager: Current focus mode 'fixed'; use auto focus? false
09-02 01:24:49.600    4263-4263/? I/Choreographer: Skipped 47 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
09-02 01:24:49.610    4263-4263/? D/CameraManager: Calculated framing rect: Rect(240, 138 - 1040, 598)
09-02 01:24:49.680      435-451/? I/ActivityManager: Displayed com.google.zxing.client.android/.CaptureActivity: +1s277ms
09-02 01:24:49.680      435-606/? W/InputMethodManagerService: Starting input on non-focused client com.android.internal.view.IInputMethodClient$Stub$Proxy@42ac36f8 (uid=10069 pid=8312)
09-02 01:24:49.690    8312-8312/com.testrotary W/IInputConnectionWrapper: showStatusIcon on inactive InputConnection
09-02 01:24:49.700      122-159/? I/hwcomposer: Setting interactive mode: Off
09-02 01:24:49.740      435-451/? I/WindowManager: Screen frozen for +1s332ms due to Window{425238e0 u0 Starting com.google.zxing.client.android}
09-02 01:24:49.790    4263-4273/? D/dalvikvm: GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 173K, 12% free 8309K/9396K, paused 95ms, total 95ms
09-02 01:24:49.800    4263-4273/? I/dalvikvm-heap: Grow heap (frag case) to 9.491MB for 1382416-byte allocation
09-02 01:24:49.820      122-159/? I/hwcomposer: Setting interactive mode: On
09-02 01:24:49.840    4263-4263/? D/dalvikvm: GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 2K, 11% free 9656K/10748K, paused 38ms, total 38ms
09-02 01:24:49.890    4263-4267/? D/dalvikvm: GC_CONCURRENT freed 4K, 11% free 9654K/10748K, paused 3ms+2ms, total 51ms
09-02 01:24:49.940    8312-8312/com.testrotary W/ZZ: Cr_rr_qrreader:onStop (BASE CLASS)
09-02 01:24:50.100    4263-7700/? D/dalvikvm: GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 1791K, 23% free 8304K/10748K, paused 27ms, total 27ms
09-02 01:24:50.100    4263-7700/? I/dalvikvm-heap: Grow heap (frag case) to 9.486MB for 1382416-byte allocation
09-02 01:24:50.130    4263-4271/? D/dalvikvm: GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 0K, 11% free 9654K/10748K, paused 29ms, total 29ms
09-02 01:24:50.150      122-159/? I/hwcomposer: Setting interactive mode: Off
09-02 01:24:50.170    4263-4267/? D/dalvikvm: GC_CONCURRENT freed 4K, 11% free 9657K/10748K, paused 3ms+10ms, total 41ms
09-02 01:24:50.350    4263-4274/? D/dalvikvm: GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 1780K, 23% free 8304K/10748K, paused 28ms, total 28ms
09-02 01:24:50.350    4263-4274/? I/dalvikvm-heap: Grow heap (frag case) to 9.486MB for 1382416-byte allocation
09-02 01:24:50.380    4263-4271/? D/dalvikvm: GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 0K, 11% free 9654K/10748K, paused 23ms, total 23ms
09-02 01:24:50.410    4263-4267/? D/dalvikvm: GC_CONCURRENT freed 6K, 11% free 9656K/10748K, paused 3ms+4ms, total 29ms
09-02 01:24:50.600    4263-4273/? D/dalvikvm: GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 1780K, 23% free 8304K/10748K, paused 30ms, total 30ms
09-02 01:24:50.600    4263-4273/? I/dalvikvm-heap: Grow heap (frag case) to 9.486MB for 1382416-byte allocation
09-02 01:24:50.630    4263-4271/? D/dalvikvm: GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 0K, 11% free 9654K/10748K, paused 28ms, total 28ms
09-02 01:24:50.660    4263-4267/? D/dalvikvm: GC_CONCURRENT freed 7K, 11% free 9656K/10748K, paused 9ms+1ms, total 33ms
09-02 01:24:50.800    4263-4546/? D/dalvikvm: GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 1777K, 23% free 8304K/10748K, paused 26ms, total 26ms
09-02 01:24:50.800    4263-4546/? I/dalvikvm-heap: Grow heap (frag case) to 9.486MB for 1382416-byte allocation
09-02 01:24:50.820    4263-4271/? D/dalvikvm: GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 0K, 11% free 9654K/10748K, paused 18ms, total 18ms
09-02 01:24:50.850    4263-4267/? D/dalvikvm: GC_CONCURRENT freed 5K, 11% free 9657K/10748K, paused 5ms+3ms, total 28ms
09-02 01:24:50.960    4263-7700/? D/dalvikvm: GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 1781K, 23% free 8304K/10748K, paused 17ms, total 17ms
09-02 01:24:50.960    4263-7700/? I/dalvikvm-heap: Grow heap (frag case) to 9.486MB for 1382416-byte allocation
09-02 01:24:50.980    4263-4271/? D/dalvikvm: GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 0K, 11% free 9654K/10748K, paused 21ms, total 21ms
09-02 01:24:51.010    4263-4267/? D/dalvikvm: GC_CONCURRENT freed 6K, 11% free 9656K/10748K, paused 9ms+2ms, total 28ms
09-02 01:24:51.200    4263-4274/? D/dalvikvm: GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 1777K, 23% free 8304K/10748K, paused 25ms, total 25ms
09-02 01:24:51.200    4263-4274/? I/dalvikvm-heap: Grow heap (frag case) to 9.486MB for 1382416-byte allocation
09-02 01:24:51.220    4263-4271/? D/dalvikvm: GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 0K, 11% free 9654K/10748K, paused 19ms, total 19ms
09-02 01:24:51.260    4263-4267/? D/dalvikvm: GC_CONCURRENT freed 9K, 11% free 9656K/10748K, paused 9ms+5ms, total 34ms
09-02 01:24:51.410    4263-4273/? D/dalvikvm: GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 1775K, 23% free 8304K/10748K, paused 23ms, total 23ms
09-02 01:24:51.410    4263-4273/? I/dalvikvm-heap: Grow heap (frag case) to 9.486MB for 1382416-byte allocation
09-02 01:24:51.430    4263-4271/? D/dalvikvm: GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 0K, 11% free 9654K/10748K, paused 24ms, total 24ms
09-02 01:24:51.470    4263-4267/? D/dalvikvm: GC_CONCURRENT freed 1K, 11% free 9656K/10748K, paused 2ms+4ms, total 40ms
09-02 01:24:51.640    4263-4546/? D/dalvikvm: GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 1785K, 23% free 8304K/10748K, paused 16ms, total 16ms
09-02 01:24:51.640    4263-4546/? I/dalvikvm-heap: Grow heap (frag case) to 9.487MB for 1382416-byte allocation
09-02 01:24:51.660    4263-4271/? D/dalvikvm: GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 0K, 11% free 9654K/10748K, paused 25ms, total 25ms
09-02 01:24:51.690    4263-4267/? D/dalvikvm: GC_CONCURRENT freed 5K, 11% free 9656K/10748K, paused 2ms+3ms, total 30ms
09-02 01:24:51.870    4263-7700/? D/dalvikvm: GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 1779K, 23% free 8304K/10748K, paused 21ms, total 21ms
09-02 01:24:51.870    4263-7700/? I/dalvikvm-heap: Grow heap (frag case) to 9.486MB for 1382416-byte allocation
09-02 01:24:51.890      435-451/? D/dalvikvm: GC_EXPLICIT freed 1189K, 27% free 20885K/28352K, paused 13ms+10ms, total 135ms
09-02 01:24:51.890    4263-4271/? D/dalvikvm: GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 0K, 11% free 9654K/10748K, paused 25ms, total 25ms
09-02 01:24:51.920    4263-4267/? D/dalvikvm: GC_CONCURRENT freed 8K, 11% free 9656K/10748K, paused 3ms+3ms, total 27ms
09-02 01:24:52.100    4263-4546/? D/dalvikvm: GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 1778K, 23% free 8304K/10748K, paused 42ms, total 42ms
09-02 01:24:52.100    4263-4546/? I/dalvikvm-heap: Grow heap (frag case) to 9.486MB for 1382416-byte allocation
09-02 01:24:52.150    4263-4271/? D/dalvikvm: GC_FOR_ALLOC freed <1K, 11% free 9654K/10748K, paused 47ms, total 47ms
09-02 01:24:52.170    4263-4267/? D/dalvikvm: GC_CONCURRENT freed 5K, 11% free 9656K/10748K, paused 3ms+6ms, total 24ms
09-02 01:24:52.260    4263-8928/? D/DecodeHandler: Found barcode in 105 ms
09-02 01:24:52.300    4263-8928/? D/dalvikvm: GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 432K, 11% free 9655K/10748K, paused 45ms, total 45ms
09-02 01:24:52.350    4263-4267/? D/dalvikvm: GC_CONCURRENT freed 2K, 4% free 10369K/10748K, paused 8ms+3ms, total 33ms
09-02 01:24:52.350    4263-8928/? D/dalvikvm: WAIT_FOR_CONCURRENT_GC blocked 7ms
09-02 01:24:52.350    4263-4263/? D/CaptureActivityHandler: Got decode succeeded message
09-02 01:24:52.380    4263-4263/? D/dalvikvm: GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 2077K, 22% free 8666K/11100K, paused 18ms, total 18ms
09-02 01:24:53.990    4263-4263/? D/CaptureActivityHandler: Got return scan result message
09-02 01:24:54.160     125-8922/? D/: Camera fd close (MI1040)
09-02 01:24:54.220      125-481/? E/NvOmxCamera: Already called release()
09-02 01:24:54.220      125-481/? I/CameraClient: Destroying camera 0
09-02 01:24:54.220      125-481/? W/NvOmxCamera: Already called release()
09-02 01:24:54.230      125-459/? W/AudioFlinger: session id 3092 not found for pid 125
09-02 01:24:54.230      125-459/? W/AudioFlinger: session id 3093 not found for pid 125
09-02 01:24:54.270      435-487/? I/InputReader: Reconfiguring input devices.  changes=0x00000004
09-02 01:24:54.270      435-487/? I/InputReader: Device reconfigured: id=2, name='elan-touchscreen', size 800x1280, orientation 0, mode 1, display id 0
09-02 01:24:54.270     435-1814/? I/ActivityManager: Config changes=1480 {1.0 310mcc?mnc en_US ldltr sw600dp w600dp h880dp 213dpi lrg port finger -keyb/v/h -nav/h s.260}
09-02 01:24:54.310    8312-8312/com.testrotary W/ZZ: Cr_rr_qrreader:onStart (BASE CLASS)
09-02 01:24:54.310    8312-8312/com.testrotary W/ZZ: Cr_rr_qrreader: start GPS is set to NO in the applications configuration data, not starting GPS
09-02 01:24:54.310    8312-8312/com.testrotary W/ZZ: Cr_rr_qrreader:onResume (BASE CLASS)
09-02 01:24:54.330      122-159/? I/hwcomposer: Setting interactive mode: On
09-02 01:24:54.390    4263-4263/? W/IInputConnectionWrapper: showStatusIcon on inactive InputConnection
09-02 01:24:54.400      520-520/? D/PhoneStatusBar: mSettingsPanelGravity = 8388661
09-02 01:24:54.420      520-520/? V/PhoneStatusBar: setLightsOn(true)
09-02 01:24:54.450  14442-14445/? D/dalvikvm: GC_CONCURRENT freed 383K, 6% free 7613K/8068K, paused 1ms+3ms, total 147ms
09-02 01:24:54.540      435-451/? I/WindowManager: Screen frozen for +302ms due to Window{4237e0a8 u0 com.testrotary/com.testrotary.Cr_rr_qrreader}
09-02 01:24:56.650      435-451/? D/dalvikvm: GC_EXPLICIT freed 631K, 26% free 21049K/28352K, paused 15ms+9ms, total 111ms
09-02 01:30:01.270  14442-14442/? V/DigitalWidgetViewsFactory: DigitalWidget sets next alarm string to null
09-02 01:30:24.050      435-508/? I/ActivityManager: Start proc com.google.android.apps.currents for service com.google.android.apps.currents/com.google.apps.dots.android.app.service.SyncService: pid=9079 uid=10009 gids={50009, 3003, 1015, 1028}
09-02 01:30:24.450    9079-9082/? D/dalvikvm: GC_CONCURRENT freed 266K, 5% free 7663K/7992K, paused 4ms+1ms, total 31ms
09-02 01:30:24.450    9079-9097/? D/ActivityThread: Loading provider com.google.android.apps.currents: com.google.apps.dots.android.currents.provider.CurrentsContentProvider
09-02 01:30:24.560    9079-9079/? W/GAV2: Thread[main,5,main]: Need to call initialize() and be in fallback mode to start dispatch.
09-02 01:30:24.740    9079-9082/? D/dalvikvm: GC_CONCURRENT freed 341K, 5% free 7833K/8236K, paused 2ms+2ms, total 20ms
09-02 01:30:24.740    9079-9079/? D/dalvikvm: WAIT_FOR_CONCURRENT_GC blocked 5ms
09-02 01:30:24.740    9079-9079/? I/DotsApplication: Starting up...
09-02 01:30:24.760    9079-9107/? I/SyncService: Starting background sync (01:30:24)
09-02 01:30:27.260    9079-9082/? D/dalvikvm: GC_CONCURRENT freed 249K, 4% free 7985K/8296K, paused 6ms+3ms, total 23ms
09-02 01:30:27.890    9079-9082/? D/dalvikvm: GC_CONCURRENT freed 337K, 5% free 8077K/8476K, paused 3ms+3ms, total 30ms
09-02 01:30:27.990    9079-9110/? D/dalvikvm: GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 111K, 4% free 8289K/8628K, paused 16ms, total 16ms
09-02 01:30:28.020    9079-9110/? D/dalvikvm: GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 348K, 7% free 8278K/8840K, paused 15ms, total 15ms
09-02 01:30:28.510    9079-9082/? D/dalvikvm: GC_CONCURRENT freed 497K, 7% free 8285K/8848K, paused 2ms+3ms, total 23ms
09-02 01:30:28.620    9079-9082/? D/dalvikvm: GC_CONCURRENT freed 258K, 4% free 8517K/8848K, paused 3ms+5ms, total 26ms
09-02 01:30:28.680    9079-9082/? D/dalvikvm: GC_CONCURRENT freed 271K, 4% free 8750K/9088K, paused 2ms+2ms, total 20ms
09-02 01:30:28.680    9079-9110/? D/dalvikvm: WAIT_FOR_CONCURRENT_GC blocked 7ms
09-02 01:30:28.730    9079-9082/? D/dalvikvm: GC_CONCURRENT freed 285K, 4% free 8972K/9324K, paused 3ms+2ms, total 25ms
09-02 01:30:28.730    9079-9110/? D/dalvikvm: WAIT_FOR_CONCURRENT_GC blocked 10ms
09-02 01:30:28.790    9079-9082/? D/dalvikvm: GC_CONCURRENT freed 335K, 5% free 9136K/9540K, paused 3ms+2ms, total 26ms
09-02 01:30:28.790    9079-9110/? D/dalvikvm: WAIT_FOR_CONCURRENT_GC blocked 4ms
09-02 01:30:28.840    9079-9082/? D/dalvikvm: GC_CONCURRENT freed 403K, 5% free 9209K/9680K, paused 2ms+2ms, total 24ms
09-02 01:30:29.160    9079-9082/? D/dalvikvm: GC_CONCURRENT freed 433K, 6% free 9275K/9776K, paused 5ms+2ms, total 35ms
09-02 01:30:29.620    9079-9082/? D/dalvikvm: GC_CONCURRENT freed 488K, 6% free 9280K/9836K, paused 3ms+3ms, total 31ms
09-02 01:30:29.760    9079-9102/? I/GAV2: Thread[GAThread,5,main]: No campaign data found.
09-02 01:30:29.930    9079-9082/? D/dalvikvm: GC_CONCURRENT freed 469K, 6% free 9405K/9940K, paused 2ms+3ms, total 26ms
09-02 01:30:30.000    9079-9082/? D/dalvikvm: GC_CONCURRENT freed 542K, 7% free 9415K/10108K, paused 3ms+1ms, total 22ms
09-02 01:30:30.000    9079-9110/? D/dalvikvm: WAIT_FOR_CONCURRENT_GC blocked 19ms
09-02 01:30:30.100    9079-9082/? D/dalvikvm: GC_CONCURRENT freed 496K, 7% free 9479K/10108K, paused 3ms+2ms, total 26ms
09-02 01:30:30.340    9079-9082/? D/dalvikvm: GC_CONCURRENT freed 712K, 8% free 9403K/10184K, paused 2ms+3ms, total 25ms
09-02 01:30:30.560    9079-9082/? D/dalvikvm: GC_CONCURRENT freed 633K, 8% free 9415K/10184K, paused 2ms+2ms, total 28ms
09-02 01:30:30.560    9079-9110/? D/dalvikvm: WAIT_FOR_CONCURRENT_GC blocked 7ms
09-02 01:30:30.770    9079-9082/? D/dalvikvm: GC_CONCURRENT freed 505K, 7% free 9512K/10184K, paused 3ms+2ms, total 26ms
09-02 01:30:30.990    9079-9082/? D/dalvikvm: GC_CONCURRENT freed 633K, 7% free 9529K/10232K, paused 3ms+3ms, total 30ms
09-02 01:30:31.090    9079-9082/? D/dalvikvm: GC_CONCURRENT freed 627K, 7% free 9585K/10280K, paused 1ms+2ms, total 25ms
09-02 01:30:31.090    9079-9110/? D/dalvikvm: WAIT_FOR_CONCURRENT_GC blocked 8ms
09-02 01:30:31.200    9079-9082/? D/dalvikvm: GC_CONCURRENT freed 560K, 7% free 9625K/10280K, paused 1ms+2ms, total 24ms
09-02 01:30:31.490    9079-9082/? D/dalvikvm: GC_CONCURRENT freed 696K, 8% free 9611K/10376K, paused 2ms+2ms, total 25ms
09-02 01:30:31.630    9079-9110/? D/dalvikvm: GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 344K, 7% free 9653K/10376K, paused 22ms, total 22ms
09-02 01:30:31.690    9079-9110/? D/dalvikvm: GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 481K, 8% free 9669K/10444K, paused 21ms, total 21ms
09-02 01:30:31.790    9079-9082/? D/dalvikvm: GC_CONCURRENT freed 615K, 7% free 9780K/10464K, paused 3ms+2ms, total 27ms
09-02 01:30:31.790    9079-9110/? D/dalvikvm: WAIT_FOR_CONCURRENT_GC blocked 6ms
09-02 01:30:32.020    9079-9082/? D/dalvikvm: GC_CONCURRENT freed 752K, 8% free 9789K/10612K, paused 3ms+2ms, total 28ms
09-02 01:30:32.020    9079-9110/? D/dalvikvm: WAIT_FOR_CONCURRENT_GC blocked 12ms
09-02 01:30:32.350    9079-9082/? D/dalvikvm: GC_CONCURRENT freed 844K, 9% free 9710K/10624K, paused 3ms+2ms, total 27ms
09-02 01:30:32.350    9079-9110/? D/dalvikvm: WAIT_FOR_CONCURRENT_GC blocked 11ms
09-02 01:30:32.570    9079-9082/? D/dalvikvm: GC_CONCURRENT freed 708K, 9% free 9724K/10624K, paused 3ms+1ms, total 27ms
09-02 01:30:32.770    9079-9082/? D/dalvikvm: GC_CONCURRENT freed 710K, 9% free 9764K/10624K, paused 4ms+2ms, total 30ms
09-02 01:30:32.770    9079-9110/? D/dalvikvm: WAIT_FOR_CONCURRENT_GC blocked 13ms
09-02 01:30:33.140    9079-9082/? D/dalvikvm: GC_CONCURRENT freed 826K, 9% free 9702K/10624K, paused 2ms+2ms, total 26ms
09-02 01:30:33.140    9079-9110/? D/dalvikvm: WAIT_FOR_CONCURRENT_GC blocked 8ms
09-02 01:30:33.320    9079-9082/? D/dalvikvm: GC_CONCURRENT freed 677K, 9% free 9757K/10624K, paused 3ms+2ms, total 27ms
09-02 01:30:33.630      435-705/? D/dalvikvm: GC_EXPLICIT freed 3092K, 26% free 21035K/28352K, paused 6ms+9ms, total 112ms
09-02 01:30:33.690    9079-9082/? D/dalvikvm: GC_CONCURRENT freed 641K, 9% free 9770K/10624K, paused 2ms+2ms, total 26ms
09-02 01:30:33.980    9079-9082/? D/dalvikvm: GC_CONCURRENT freed 1147K, 12% free 9389K/10624K, paused 3ms+2ms, total 27ms
09-02 01:30:33.980    9079-9110/? D/dalvikvm: WAIT_FOR_CONCURRENT_GC blocked 10ms
09-02 01:30:34.230    9079-9082/? D/dalvikvm: GC_CONCURRENT freed 634K, 12% free 9393K/10624K, paused 1ms+2ms, total 25ms
09-02 01:30:34.230    9079-9110/? D/dalvikvm: WAIT_FOR_CONCURRENT_GC blocked 9ms
09-02 01:30:34.420    9079-9082/? D/dalvikvm: GC_CONCURRENT freed 637K, 12% free 9398K/10624K, paused 3ms+2ms, total 26ms
09-02 01:30:34.420    9079-9110/? D/dalvikvm: WAIT_FOR_CONCURRENT_GC blocked 8ms
09-02 01:30:34.620    9079-9082/? D/dalvikvm: GC_CONCURRENT freed 597K, 12% free 9416K/10624K, paused 1ms+3ms, total 24ms
09-02 01:30:34.800    9079-9082/? D/dalvikvm: GC_CONCURRENT freed 555K, 11% free 9510K/10624K, paused 1ms+2ms, total 24ms
09-02 01:30:34.800    9079-9110/? D/dalvikvm: WAIT_FOR_CONCURRENT_GC blocked 8ms
09-02 01:30:37.270    9079-9082/? D/dalvikvm: GC_CONCURRENT freed 492K, 9% free 9698K/10624K, paused 2ms+2ms, total 25ms
09-02 01:30:37.270    9079-9110/? D/dalvikvm: WAIT_FOR_CONCURRENT_GC blocked 15ms
09-02 01:30:37.350    9079-9082/? D/dalvikvm: GC_CONCURRENT freed 159K, 4% free 10282K/10624K, paused 1ms+2ms, total 27ms
09-02 01:30:37.350    9079-9110/? D/dalvikvm: WAIT_FOR_CONCURRENT_GC blocked 14ms
09-02 01:30:37.480    9079-9082/? D/dalvikvm: GC_CONCURRENT freed 1108K, 11% free 10104K/11280K, paused 1ms+4ms, total 39ms
09-02 01:30:37.480    9079-9110/? D/dalvikvm: WAIT_FOR_CONCURRENT_GC blocked 26ms
09-02 01:30:37.580    9079-9082/? D/dalvikvm: GC_CONCURRENT freed 1589K, 17% free 9393K/11280K, paused 3ms+2ms, total 29ms
09-02 01:30:37.580    9079-9110/? D/dalvikvm: WAIT_FOR_CONCURRENT_GC blocked 10ms
09-02 01:30:37.650    9079-9082/? D/dalvikvm: GC_CONCURRENT freed 612K, 17% free 9402K/11280K, paused 3ms+3ms, total 27ms
09-02 01:30:37.720    9079-9082/? D/dalvikvm: GC_CONCURRENT freed 613K, 17% free 9429K/11280K, paused 2ms+2ms, total 26ms
09-02 01:30:37.720    9079-9110/? D/dalvikvm: WAIT_FOR_CONCURRENT_GC blocked 9ms
09-02 01:30:37.740    9079-9107/? I/SyncService: sync service finished (01:30:37)
09-02 01:32:50.500      435-474/? W/ActivityManager: Unable to start service Intent { flg=0x4 cmp=com.google.android.apps.maps/com.google.googlenav.prefetch.android.PrefetcherService (has extras) } U=0: not found
09-02 01:32:59.940   27449-9143/? W/l: [TiclService] Skipping unknown enum class name ah
09-02 01:32:59.940   27449-9143/? W/l: [TiclService] Skipping unknown enum class name ah
09-02 01:32:59.980  27449-27453/? D/dalvikvm: GC_CONCURRENT freed 478K, 7% free 7816K/8356K, paused 8ms+1ms, total 72ms
09-02 01:33:00.610   27449-9152/? W/MsgSenderSvc: IOException sending to the data center (https://clients4.google.com//invalidation/android/request/CHES6wESzAFBUEE5MWJHWHV3N21JUVBxQ0h2bWJubERVdXd4MUtkLVNob29MbG8xNWI5Q2x1WXVfZlliNHhwaVVJZUh3Ti02LTB0UmJiY2pyeEZjV3NQSG5GbVRKUGZjMDB6NXByZkZydFVxbV93ZmNob0tVbHpsNGVhUFJXMGExcjI0MjZSZGVCam1JcHF3emduTGVaYUNhUmZnS3hlZWNTNlJLUFd1TEVPOWdkaC1BN1FNemtIZjBSUl9iUWgzX2o4dHRBTlE2LXNYRTJ2cWZ4ZzgaACoECAAQADISY29tLmFuZHJvaWQuY2hyb21l?service=chromiumsync): java.io.EOFException
```

What's strange is that the QR Code Reader app briefly shows the text from the QR Code before exiting back to my app.  So the code was scanned successfully.  However, when my app is returned, the onActivityResult doesn't fire.

I'm guessing it's a problem with something (the IntentIntegrator maybe?) not being released from memory properly.

I'm testing this on a Google Nexus 7 (1st gen) device using the front camera.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I fixed it.  Changed the calling method to:

```
public void performScan(){
IntentIntegrator scanIntegrator = new IntentIntegrator(this);
                scanIntegrator.initiateScan();
}
```

("thisActivity") was previously being defined and must have been released along the way.